# Geometry Nodes: can I animate (trim) a curve in real time at the moment I'm drawing it?

Tags: geometry-nodes

in the asset from Blender Studio, [2D Smoke Simulation Setup](https://studio.blender.org/films/wing-it/gallery/?asset=6834)
smoke is animated in real time each time a new spline in drawn.

[image]

How could I reproduce that ?  I would like to animate a spline (trim) each time it has been drawned.
Thanks !

Comment: When you render something, Blender doesn't take previous frame to modify it slightly. It generates a new frame from scratch (OK, rarely some very limited data is cached and reused). So the question is hard to understand, it would be harder to, for some reason, reuse the spline. \

Comment: There is a downloadable blend file in the link you indicated in the question. All is there.